# Unable to authenticate to Azure Devops Server on premise with Macos selft hosted agent

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent, azure-devops-server-2020

On my mac, I have a VM with Windows server 2019 and Azure Devops Server 2020 (update 1.1).

I can go to my dashboard (http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/MyProjectCollection) correctly from Chrome on my mac, using the Windows server's admin login (Administrator) and password (IWontTellYou).

When I try to configure a self hosted agent (2.190.0) on my mac, I run ./config.sh in a terminal but I cannot validate the authentication process...

I cannot use PAT nor Alternate because my server is not on HTTPS.
I cannot use Integrated because I am on mac.
I use Negotiate, but I can't get authenticated :

```
Enter server URL > http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/MyProjectCollection/
Enter authentication type (press enter for Negotiate) > Negotiate
Enter user name > Administrator
Enter password > *************
VS30063: You are not authorized to access http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.
Failed to connect.  Try again or ctrl-c to quit
```

Why does it works on Chrome but mot with the self hosted agent ?

How can I authenticate please ?

Thanks for any help... I have reinstalled Windows Server and Azure Devops Server several times to try several configuration, including activating HTTPS using a self signed ssl certificate to use PAT, but nothing works :(

Edit : I've tryed with a Windows self hsoted agent on the server, here is the powershell output :

```
Enter server URL > http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/MyProjectCollection
Enter authentication type (press enter for Integrated) > Negotiate
Enter user name > Administrator
Enter password > *************
Error reported in diagnostic logs. Please examine the log for more details.
    - C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.181.2\_diag\Agent_20210820-064419-utc.log
TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required.
Failed to connect.  Try again or ctrl-c to quit
Enter server URL > http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/MyProjectCollection
Enter authentication type (press enter for Integrated) >
Connecting to server ...
```

Comment: When you use the steps to configure a Windows Agent, will it work?

Comment: Thank you @KevinLu-MSFT for your answer. I've try on a windows self hosted agent, the Negotiate authentication doesn't work but Integrated works (on the server itslef). I've updated the question with the powershell output. The error is quite more explicit, I'll try to search about anonymous access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use a https URL and deactivate the sslhandshake.

Tap the following command to configure the self hosted agent and ignore the https certificate validation :

```
./config.sh -–sslskipcertvalidation
```

Then replace the http by https in your URL :

```
Enter server URL > https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/MyProjectCollection
```

You can now use PAT authentication method to authenticate and configure the self hosted agent.
Follow this doc to configure a PAT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/windows-agent?view=azure-devops#authenticate-with-a-personal-access-token-pat

As the PAT is used only one time to configure the self hosted agentm you can remove it once the configuration is successful.